# Name change in lotus notes, do emails get automatically forwarded?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

When changing a name in notes will the emails sent to the old email address (firstnameoldlastname@email.com) get redirected to the new email address (firstnamenewlastname@email.com) automatically?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes.

The long answer is that as long as you aren't stuck on a mid-1990s version Lotus Notes, and as long as your Lotus Domino server is set up correctly, then your old email address should be maintained as an alias in your Person document in the Domino Directory.